# What does "on" mean in "not minute too soon on this transmitter"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

A situation: a man arrived to the radio/TV transmitter to fix it and he tell yourself:

> Boy,  I wasn't a minute too soon on this transmitter.

I want to know what is the meaning of the preposition "on". Is there a direct bound with "be"- verb at the beginning sentence? Or does it show the place where the man arrived to?

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of context, "on" means *with respect to*, or *having (the thing mentioned) as a target, aim, or focus*.

The man had arrived to *work on* the transmitter (fixing it), and he says he arrived in a timely fashion (this is what the idiom "not a minute too soon" means) to do so.